# How to use twitch api?

Tags: python, python-requests, twitch-api

I have been recently reading about the Twitch API reference to figure out getting channel ids by username, but have no idea how to use it. https://api.twitch.tv/helix/users is the link where I was sending my params.

```
URL = "https://api.twitch.tv/helix/users"
channelName = {'OAuth': os.environ["Oauth"]}

r = requests.get(url=URL, params=channelName)
print(r.text)

Message:
{"error":"Unauthorized","status":401,"message":"OAuth token is missing"}
```

I provided the token so I don't know where I went wrong. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Through the API itself you would use the twitch login name with

`GET https://api.twitch.tv/helix/users?login=<login name>&login=<login name>`

With the return values you can acquire the ID.

You can find the query and response information at

https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/api/reference#get-users

Though the error you're seeing means you haven't generated or setup a token required to make these requests from the Twitch API. You need to make sure you're going through the setup process and utilizing the client-ID and Oath token to make your requests.

More information on how to get started: https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/api#step-1-setup